# Why are most (if not all) German words for "cheap" euphemisms?

Tags: adjective, euphemism

Many German words for "cheap" are euphemisms. Why is that the case? 
The interpretation of these words just occurred to me, it might not be etymologically correct. I am not a linguist:

Preiswert = Es ist seinen Preis wert.

Günstig = Es hat meine Gunst.

Billig = Es ist mir billig. Ich billige das. (Im Sinne von: Es ist mir recht)

Comment: Das sind keine Euphemismen, oder zumindest sehe ich nicht, warum Du sie als solche empfindest. Was ist deine eigentliche Frage?

Comment: Euphemisms? Warum ist eine direkte Übersetzung von *cheap* zu vermeiden? Ich find' doch da weder etwas Böses noch Vulgäres.

Comment: So wie ich es sehe, versuchen diese Worte nicht nur zu sagen, dass etwas wenig kostet, sondern sie enthalten indirekt auch eine Rechtfertigung und versuchen zu beschoenigen, dass man den Preis nur ok findet, weil er gering ist. Sie versuchen meiner Meinung nach auszudruecken, dass hinter einem Preis ein gutes Preis-Leistungs-Verhaeltnis steht.

Comment: @c.p. : Es geht mir nicht darum, eine Uebersetzung zu vermeiden, zumal ich auch den Ursprung von cheap nicht kenne. Vielmehr finde ich, dass der normale Sprachgebrauch direkte Uebersetzungen vermeidet, da er billig, guenstig oder preiswert verwendet. Wir haben uns an diese Worte so gewoehnt, dass sie fuer uns jetzt das entsprechene Wort bezeichnen, so aehnlich wie die Fortschreibung von Euphemismen (Quelle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) Vielleicht ist das ja auch die Antwort? Scham darueber, dass man etwas von geringem Preis gekauft hat?

Comment: @SebastianLanger ach so, entschuldige, ich habe total falsch gelesen. Welche wäre denn eine Übersetzung, die kein Eufemismus ist?

Comment: Hast Du eine Quelle für Deine Erklärungen der Wortherkünfte? Ich könnte mir z. B. bei *günstig* auch vorstellen, dass es genau umgekehrt ist, und zwar dass es ausdrückt, dass der niedrige Preis mir zu Gunsten ist. Inbesondere die Verwendung von *günstig* für etwas anderes als Preise legt dies nahe.

Comment: Hier nal ganz kurz zwischenrein: *" he's a cheap person "*. Cheap != nicht teuer....

Comment: Vielleicht verstehe ich deine Frage ja falsch, aber die Wörter wurden gerade in den letzten Jahren dadurch geprägt, dass diverse Discounter mit "billig" warben und zugleich bei vielen Menschen als qualitätsschlecht (=billig) verurteilt wurden.

Comment: Richtig ist wohl, wie auch schon von @Em1 angedeutet, dass alle diese Wörter ursprünglich positiv sind, *billig* inzwischen aber häufig negativ besetzt ist. Das englische *[cheap](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cheap)* hat die negative Konnotation übrigens auch erst später erhalten.

Comment: @c.p. : Ja, das weiss ich eben auch nicht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft : Nein, eine Quelle habe ich nicht. Ich bin auch in Etymologie voellig unbewandert. Das es sich genau umgekehrt verhaelt, ist eine Moeglichkeit, die ich gar nicht in Betracht gezogen habe, die aber auch nicht schlechter ist als meine Vermutungen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words in their original meaning from today's perspective may be euphemisms but the meaning now is just the meaning now. 
People do not think of a connection to *billigen* when they hear *billig*. Same for *günstig* and *preiswert* which by the way is pretty neutral. 
There is nothing euphemistic about these words today.

Comment: This is good statement, but not really an answer to my question - possibly because the question is based on false premises in the first place. I'll upvote you and think about accepting the answer.

Comment: @SebastianLanger I know what you mean. But the headline of your question implies that they are euphemisms now. Had you asked "Why did they all evolve from such?", I would have not known what to say, because it seems a true observation.

Answer (score 2):

There are subtle differences:

*billig* often means cheap in the sense that it is of bad quality. So you'll for instance say that "Das Gehäuse sieht billig aus" meaning that the casing looks cheap, bad. You also have it in terms like "Eine billige Anmache" (a cheap pass on someone).

When saying *preiswert*, I still mean it in the sense "It is worth it's price". I would not say "Das Gehäuse sieht preiswert aus" to say that it looks cheap. When I buy a "preiswert" computer, it means that it has a good price/value ratio.

*günstig* is neutral for me, but often refers to a good opportunity. Just imagine you want to buy yourself a new car which costs you 25.000 €, but you get it for 22.000 € because it is in green, which you don't mind, then it was "günstig".

Comment: Selbst billiges Aussehen muss nicht abwertend sein. Oft sollen Geräte in gebürstetem Metalllook teuer aussehen und sehen auch teurer aus als buntes Plastik und trotzdem kann mir das billig aussehende Gehäuse besser gefallen. Es ist nur die Frage ob man sich ein Geschmacksurteil unabhängig vom Preis oder vermuteten Preis erlaubt oder ob man sich einem angenommenen Massengeschmack unterwirft.